# How do I use elements of list to set the key and value of dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to use element 0 of `words` as a dictionary key and set the value of `to_nato` for that key to `words` element 1.

I have this:

```
natofile = "nato-alphabet.txt"
to_nato = {} #creates empty string
fh = open(natofile) #opens natofile

for line in fh: 
    clean = line.strip()
    lowerl = clean.lower()
    words = lowerl.split()
    to_nato = {words[0]:words[1]}
    print(to_nato)
```

nato-alphabet is a text file that looks like this:

```
A Alfa
B Bravo
C Charlie
D Delta
E Echo
F Foxtrot
G Golf
H Hotel
I India
```

My code returns a list of dictionaries instead one dictionary.

Comment: Of course, because you do `to_nato = {words[0]:words[1]}`. But you already defined a dictionary outside the loop! `to_nato = {}` instead of doing `to_nato = {words[0]:words[1]}` in the loop body, how would you *modify the existing dictionary* to set the value of the key `words[0]` to the value `words[1]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly set the key value with `dict_object[key] = value`:

```py
to_nato[words[0]] = words[1]
```

This can be written more concisely using the `dict` constructor and a generator expression.

```py
to_nato = dict(line.lower().split() for line in fh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
natofile = "nato-alphabet.txt"
to_nato = {} #creates empty string
fh = open(natofile) #opens natofile

for line in fh: 
    clean = line.strip()
    lowerl = clean.lower()
    words = lowerl.split()
    to_nato[words[0]] = words[1]

fh.close()

print(to_nato)
```

This sets the element of `to_nato` with key `words[0]` to value `words[1]` for each pair in the file.

Answer (score 0):

dict() can convert any list of pairs of values into a dict

```
lines=open('nato-alphabet.txt').read().lower().splitlines()
lines = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]
my_dict=dict(lines)
```